# Twilio - Page number out of range Exception

Tags: java, rest, twilio, phone-number

I have an application that interacts with Twilio. My Twilio account has 2000+ numbers and my app tries to retrieve them all. This is required and there is no way around this.

I use the following snippet of code to iterate across all numbers,

```
        try {
        // Initiate Twilio RESTful session
        TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(/* sid */, /* token */);
        IncomingPhoneNumberList numbers = client.getAccount().getIncomingPhoneNumbers();
        LogMsg.info("Attempting to retrieve phone numbers", "Phone Numbers");

        // Loop over numbers and print out a property for each one.
        for (IncomingPhoneNumber number : numbers) {
            // Twilio Phone number
            String twilioNumber = number.getPhoneNumber();

            /*
             * ...
             */
        }
       }
```

I keep getting,

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException: Page number out of range

From what I see, I'm usually at the 1400th number when this happens. Since I'm not doing anything specific with pages, I don't understand why I'm getting this error. Is there anything I can do to be able to iterate across all my numbers?

Thanks

Comment: That is odd. As far as I can tell, the Java library is trying to iterate through all the pages of numbers you have (page maximum size is 1000, though default is 50). I'd raise this as an issue on the GitHub repo for the Java library (https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java).

Comment: Darn. I was hoping I was doing something wrong. But after googling around for a bit, it seems like I'm the only one on the internet that's run into this issue. I guess I'll try raising the issue.

Comment: You might try asking for 1000 at a time rather than 50, but I'm not sure it will necessarily help. I'm no good with Java, so I can't debug this myself, I'm afraid.

Comment: I tried that. It just failed when retrieving the third page... What's weird is that I haven't been able to reproduce the issue since yesterday. I'm assuming it was something on Twilio's end? I think I might not raise the issue after all. It seems more akin to some freak accident than an actual bug.

Comment: Ah, it might well have been something on our side then. Glad it's sorted now. If it happens again, give help@twilio.com a call.

Comment: Thanks! I opened up Twilio request ticket and I'll be following up the issue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be something wrong on Twilio's end. I have not since received that error.